# NullPointerException when using Comparator.nullsLast

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have below code with 2 classes MyRange and MyCustomValue -

```
class MyRange {
    private Long id;
    private Double minValue;
    private Double maxValue;

    // getters and setters
    // equals, hashCode and toString

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyRange other = (MyRange) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id) && 
               Objects.equals(this.minValue, other.minValue) &&
               Objects.equals(this.maxValue, other.maxValue);
    }
}

class MyCustomValue {
    private String value;
    private MyRange myrange;

    //getters and setters
    // equals, hashCode and toString

}
```

If the `value` is null in `MyCustomValue` I want it in last. So I write the comparator like below

```
public static final Comparator<MyCustomValue> externalMVComparator = (emv1, emv2) -> {
    if(emv1.getValue() != null && emv2.getValue() == null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (emv1.getValue() == null && emv2.getValue() != null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return myrangeMinValueComparator.compare(emv1, emv2);
    }
}

private static final Comparator<MyRange> minValueComparator =  Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparingDouble(value -> value.getMinValue()));
private static final Comparator<MyCustomValue> myrangeMinValueComparator = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(MyCustomValue::getMyrange, minValueComparator));
```

The above comparator is working fine. So I decided to change `externalMVComparator` like below (i.e, using `thenComparing` for more readability)

```
private static final Comparator<MyCustomValue> valueComparator = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(MyCustomValue::getValue));
public static final Comparator<MyCustomValue> externalMVComparator2 = Comparator.nullsLast(valueComparator.thenComparing(myrangeMinValueComparator));
```

But sorting the list with `externalMVComparator2` results in `NullPointerException`. What is that wrong I'm doie mistake in my code?

Code used for testing -

```
MyCustomValue emv1 = new MyCustomValue("v1", new MyRange(1L, 0.71, 0.79));
MyCustomValue emv2 = new MyCustomValue(null, new MyRange(2L, 0.53, 0.65));
MyCustomValue emv3 = new MyCustomValue("v2", new MyRange(3L, 0.28, 0.42));
MyCustomValue emv4 = new MyCustomValue(null, new MyRange(4L, 0.06, 0.27));
List<MyCustomValue> shuffledList1 = Arrays.asList(emv1, emv2, emv3, emv4);
Collections.shuffle(shuffledList1);
shuffledList1.sort(MyCustomValue.externalMVComparator2);
Assert.assertEquals(shuffledList1, Arrays.asList(emv3, emv1, emv4, emv2));
```

error stacktrace -

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216)
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(Arrays.java:3895)
    at TestNullComparator.main(TestNullComparator.java:15)
```

Comment: Could you post the Stack Trace please?

Comment: @MiguelGarnachoVélez - I'm not sure how much stack trace would be help I have updated the test code as well as stacktrace inline the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in the following line (I removed `Comparator.` for clarity):

```
Comparator<MyCustomValue> valueComparator = nullsLast(comparing(MyCustomValue::getValue));
```

The `Comparator` you made will handle `null` values of `MyCustomValue` type.  It will NOT handle `null`s returned by `getValue`.  You have to use the 2-argument version of `Comparator.comparing` and supply a `null`-safe comparator for the values:

```
valueComparator = comparing(MyCustomValue::getValue, nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
```

The above will handle the common case where you actually want to sort by `value`.  As I look at your code, I think you mean to only use the `value` for `null` check and otherwise don't want to sort by it.  If that is the case, you can use `nullsLast( (x,y) -> 0)`  as the null-safe 2nd argument for `comparing` that will consider all strings as equal.  You can also use `valueComparator = comparing(mcv -> mcv.getValue() == null)` because `true` goes after `false` in natural ordering, but that might be less clear.

If you also want to handle `null`s of `MyCustomValue`, you would have to wrap it in `nullsLast` again.

Comment: Instead of `nullsLast( (x,y) -> 0)`, you can simply use `nullsLast(null)`.